# Shock formation for conservation law with initial and boundary data

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, hyperbolic-equations

Suppose we have $$u_t + f(u) u_x = 0$$ where $t, x > 0$, and initial conditions $u(x,0) = C$, where $C>0$ is constant, and $u(0,t) = g(t)$, where $t>0$. We know the solution is $$u(x,t) = F(x-f(u) t )$$ for any differentiable $F$, and characteristics are given by $x - f(u)t = r $. I am trying to find where shocks will form and find the solution in such case.

However, I don't quite understand the problem since $u(x,0) = F(x) = C$ and so $$u(x,t) = F( x - ct) = C $$ so the solution is a constant. What is my mistake here?

Comment: Observe that $F(x)=C$ only if $x>0$. In other words, you only know that the solution is a constant where $x-ct>0$. On the rest of the $(x,t)$-plane, the solution is defined by the condition at $t=0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This follows from the method of characteristics, which provides two sets of curves. The first set of curves is deduced from the initial data. It corresponds to the lines $x = f(C)t + x_0$ along which $u=C$ is constant ($x_0>0$). The second set of curves is deduced from the boundary data. It corresponds to the lines $x=f\circ g(t_0)\, (t-t_0)$ along which $u=g(t_0)$ is constant ($t_0>0$). The restriction $t,x>0$ imposes that all characteristics have positive slope, i.e. $f(C)$ and $f\circ g$ are positive. Moreover, we assume that $g(0) = C$ for compatibility. A shock can only occur in the second family of characteristic curves. To examine the dependence of the solution to the boundary data (see e.g. [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2551287/418542) for the case of initial data), we differentiate the expression of characteristic curves w.r.t. $t_0$:
$$
\frac{\text d x}{\text d t_0} = (f\circ g)'(t_0)\, (t-t_0) - f\circ g(t_0) .
$$
The minimum positive time $t$ which makes this derivative vanish is the breaking time
$$
t_b = \inf_{t_0>0} t_0 + \frac{f\circ g(t_0)}{(f\circ g)'(t_0)} \geq 0 .
$$
For example, let us consider Burgers' equation $f: u\mapsto u$ with the sinusoidal boundary data defined by $C=1$ and $g(t) = 1+\sin (\pi t)\, \Bbb I_{[0, 1]}(t)$. In this case, a shock forms at $t_b = 0$. If instead $g(t) = 1+\sin^2 (\pi t)\, \Bbb I_{[0, 1]}(t)$, then a shock forms at $t_b \approx 0.6241$.